# mysqli_fetch_array() error expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Tags: php, html, mysqli

[mysqli_fetch_array error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9j3k.jpg)

Hi, I'm mostly self taught in coding with php and mysqli. I can't, however, figure out for the life of me why this code is not working. I've used the same code twice before and it worked fine, but for some reason I can't get it to work this time. Please, any help would appreciated.

```
        <?php
    //Database Connection
        include 'dbconn.php';
    //Get ID from Database
        if(isset($_GET['edit_id'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM packages WHERE packageno =" .$_GET['edit_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
//Update Information
    if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){
    $packageno = $_POST['packageno'];
    $packagename = $_POST['packagename'];
    $packagetime = $_POST['packagetime'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $update = "UPDATE packages SET packageno='$packageno', packagename='$packagename',pacakagetime='$pacakagetime', $price='$price' WHERE packageno=". $_GET['edit_id'];
    $up = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    if(!isset($sql)){
    die ("Error $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
    header("location: packedit.php");
    }
    }
   ?>

    <!--Create Edit form -->
<center>
<form method="post">
<h1>Edit Appointment Details</h1>
<label>Package Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="packageno" placeholder="Package Num" value="<?php echo $row['packageno']; ?>"><br/><br/>
<label>Package Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="packagename" placeholder="Package Name" value="<?php echo $row['packagename']; ?>"><br/><br/>
<label>Package Time:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="packagetime" placeholder="Time" value="<?php echo $row['packagetime']; ?>"><br/><br/>
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="decimal" name="price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"><br/><br/>

<button type="submit" name="btn-update" id="btn-update" onClick="update()"><strong>Update</strong></button>
<a href="packedit.php"><button type="button" value="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: check $result is set before mysqli_fetch_array, if doesn't query have some issue or result is empty

Comment: `$_GET['edit_id']` and form is POST . from where this value is coming?

Comment: Your query has some errors please show the schema of table

Comment: @ Alive to Die may be from url, no element with name edit_id

Comment: that is my question because that may cause the falure of query

Comment: @shashi bear with me but how do I check if $result is set before mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: @Nishki use isset( $result ) check if something is there before accessing it

Comment: @AlivetoDie the values are coming from my database... unless that was an obvious answer? I'm sorry, I'm still learning

Comment: @NishkiMohan  i am unable to get you  on this `unless that was an obvious answer?`. what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @alivetodie what i meant was that I was supposed to know the answer to your question but I don't. My values are coming from my database like i said before

Comment: I don't think `coming from db` will work, because when you submit form that value will gone (from url also,because of page refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Query in your phpmyadmin and check if is there any error or not.

if there is no error than try to print  *$conn*  variable. if it gives you proper result. try to print *$result* in your case *$result returns false*.

As per my understanding there is some issue in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your query. This error occurs mostly when the name of table mentioned in query not exists or spelling mistake or the id ($_GET['edit_id']) you entered is not valid.